# How to connect mhz transmitter arduino

Tags: remote, arduino, connection, cable

How am I supposed to connect a transmitter to my raspberry pi "pins"?

[I have bought a transmitter online](http://www.miniinthebox.com/nl/433mhz-draadloze-zender-module-superregeneration-voor-arduino-groen_p411875.html)

[image]

But I have to wait about 10-15 days before its delivered, so I want to make sure that thats all I need to connect it. I assume I need some kind of cables to connect the transmitter to the pi, or am I wrong?

I want to send out signals to a remote controller outlet so I can switch appliances on and off.

If I need cables, would you please send me which (preferable on the same site as I bought the transmitter) and on which pins I have to connect them to (if it is always the same pins).

*As you maybe noticed, I'm a bit of a noob in those connections. I did see some "arduino" boards, is that what I need? If so which is the cheapest and does the trick?*

Comment: Welcome to the Pi Q&A :) What is the model of the outlet and do you know the algorithm and commands to send to the outlet? How did you know to buy 433mhz and not 900Mhz? or any other?

Comment: Here's some useful info: http://www.themagpi.com/issue/issue-8/article/home-automation-the-santa-trap/

Comment: @francis Thanks, thats quite helpfull, i must say im quite NOOB to this so even knowing which cable to use is important to me. 
and to ppumkin actually i got this idea from the post here: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/7552/12629 Where you commented aswell. I want to do exactly the same but i need a bit more detail to understand it.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I'd like to mention, this transmitter has quite poor transmission/reception quality, you'll constantly will receive some garbage, especially if you have other computer equipment working around. should have bought something based on TI CC1010 or CC1020 instead.

Secondly, you'll need TWO of these to establish a communication link, one as a transmitter and another as a receiver. if your receiving end has a different kind of receiver, you're most probably out of luck.

Finally, you'd better solder a piece of wire (about 17cm for 433Mhz version) to the "ANT" hole, this will greatly improve the chances of your data getting through.

Regarding the connection, you'll need three wires, one connecting GND to GND on your Pi, another connecting VCC to +5V and the last one connecting data pin to the output pin (not sure which one you'll decide to use).

Comment: Thanks for your response, i must say i bought 2 of these if something goes wrong, but i only want to transmit signals, i want to use my raspberry pi via python script to send out signals like explained here: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7524/cheapest-way-to-controlling-multiple-lights-through-wi-fi/7552#7552