# Control pump via raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, power, software-development

I have a pump that is powered when plugged into the mains.

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B running Raspbian Jessie.

1. How can I switch this pump on/off via software running on the raspberry pi? (Ideally Java?)
2. Is it possible to power this pump with multiple raspberry pi instead of using the mains?

[image: Pond Pump]

Pump: http://www.hozelock.com/aquatics/pumps/filter-pumps/titan/titan-3000.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 2: NO. This pump needs 230V mains voltage (AC) ... the rPi supplies 5V and 3V3, both DC.

Question 1 has been answered a gazillion times on this site as well as on the rest of the internet, just google for "Raspberry Pi AC pump relay" - for example this article on this site: [How can one control AC power (220V) with a Raspberry Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1633/how-can-one-control-ac-power-220v-with-a-raspberry-pi)

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't realised an "AC pump relay" was what I was looking for.