# How can I measure current with RPi at high voltage/high current (100-120V / 0-30A)

Tags: power, measuring

How could I measure current with a raspberry pi at voltages and currents that can be found inside a typical home's power outlets?

The goal is to create a device that monitors how much energy is being used through a particular outlet.

Comment: Vlad, your question is overly broad, and as such will likely be closed. This isn't a tutorial site. If you have questions about specific components of your problem, please feel free to ask more detailed questions.

Comment: Also, please be **extremely careful** when dealing with these types of projects. The mains power is extremely dangerous, and your question implies that you don't have the prerequisite knowledge required to **safely and legally** make such a device.

Comment: @Jacobm001 [this question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1633/how-can-one-control-ac-power-220v-with-a-raspberry-pi) is a great example of this type of question that has been received very well on this site, and is just as broad as the current question.

Answer (score 3):

I reckon [emonPi](https://guide.openenergymonitor.org/setup/) is what you should be looking for.

As @Jacobm001 said, you should be **extremely** careful when messing around with the mains voltage and maybe it is a good to buy a preassembled one.

You can do a lot of things using the [provided dashboard](https://guide.openenergymonitor.org/setup/dashboards/) or [the Node-RED integration](https://guide.openenergymonitor.org/integrations/nodered/) they offer.

Answer (score 2):

Radioshack sells a VOM that has a serial port and a API to interact with the meter.

You could get a "premade" device such as this if it has a customizable API.
Then just code a pi interface to it.

edit: requested link

[RadioShack 22-812](https://sigrok.org/wiki/RadioShack_22-812)

Comment: Could you had a link to such a device?

Comment: I just realized current (amps) is voltage divided by resistance :/

Comment: @PandaLion98 No, the one I use is a VOM. Not sure of any ammeters that have a serial interface.